# The replication agent encountered a failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, merge-replication

I have created a new merge replication. I am facing this issue:

When I go to ​start the 'View Agent Snapshot Status', it shows an error:

[image]

I clicked start but still got the same error.

I have viewed at the job history:

[image]

when I select step id 2 the following error message appears:

[image]

Step id 3 the following error message appears:

[image]

Step id 1 the following successful message appears:

[image]

Step id 2 the following successful message appears:

[image]

id step 2 notice an exception:

[image]

Please show me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you also attach the full message for the other *successful* rows for step 2? Sometimes the actual error message is at the end of the last successful step's message.

Comment: I have attached the full message for the other successful rows. There is an exception at step 2. But I don't know how to fix it? Can you help me?

Comment: Unfortunately it sounds like you have a very specific issue going on that's not possible to be debugged on here. You can try following the answer [on here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c2e90264-7d8b-42af-b109-ac5d4735d51e/transactional-replication-error?forum=sqlreplication) but your best bet is to contact Microsoft for support and/or try [repairing the installation of your SQL Server instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/repair-a-failed-sql-server-installation?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: After I try repairing the installation of your SQL Server instance, I get this warning:

The following warnings were encountered while configuring settings on your SQL Server. These resources / settings were missing or invalid so default values were used in recreating the missing resources. Please review to make sure they don't require further customization for your applications:
Service SID support has been enabled on the service.
Service SID support has been enabled on the service.

What should I do next?

Comment: Is Replication working now?...if not, what happens when you [reinitialize the subscription with a new snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/reinitialize-a-subscription?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: oh, replication worked. Thank you very much!